# using safenet LUNA Api with eclipse (LunaTokenManager)

Tags: java, eclipse, keystore

I have implemented a test unit to load Luna keystore but something is wrong when i try to initialize the "LunaTokenManager":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    LunaTokenManager tokenManager = LunaTokenManager.getInstance();
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

i got the following message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaAPI.Initialize()V
at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaAPI.Initialize(Native Method)
at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaTokenManager.<init>(LunaTokenManager.java:107)
at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaTokenManager.getInstance(LunaTokenManager.java:62)
at it.tasgroup.eacs.service.TestKeystoreWithLunaSA.main(TestKeystoreWithLunaSA.java:14)
```

LunaApi.ddl is placed in C:\Program Files\LunaSA\JSP\lib
Provider.jar is placed in the %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ext
both path are configured in environment variables

the two jar "LunaJCASP-1.0.0.jar" and "LunaJCESP-1.0.0.jar" are included as lib into eclipse buildpath

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:
1.- You're not specifying correctly the path to your libraries.
2.- Permissions issue between your process and the library directory