# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaAPI.Initialize()V

Tags: hsm

I am getting below exception while running my application.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaAPI.Initialize()V
>           at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaAPI.Initialize(Native Method)
>           at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaTokenManager.(LunaTokenManager.java:107)
>           at com.chrysalisits.crypto.LunaTokenManager.getInstance(LunaTokenManager.java:62)

I have added `LunaProvider.jar` and `libLunaAPI` in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.
Actual Problem was mismatch between native client library (libLunaAPI.so) and Luna client.

My application was using old library's com.chrysalisits.crypto.* classes to interact with Luna client however my Luna client got updated and functions which it exposed in its native library was not present in current library.

I updated my client application by using com.safenetinc.luna.* classes and latest client library.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you ask the HSM Support Team for help on this instead of Stackoverflow.

This error comes up if Java is not able to find the concerned .so / .dll (Library) file. Also, make sure that you have the correct 32 / 64 Bit version of the Library in the location.

That said, in the VM Arguments you could also set :

```
-Djava.library.path=/location_to_the_libLunaAPI_so_file (possibly, /usr/lunasa/JSP/lib .. or something)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have added libLunaAPI.so and LunaProvider.jar in java library path but error is still same

Comment: Just put it (libLunaAPI.so) in the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib ... see if that helps , also try $JRE_HOME/lib ...

Comment: @user1186213 in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958755/using-safenet-luna-api-with-eclipse-lunatokenmanager) you said that you have solved the problem can you tell me please how you solved this one.